# svg to jpg (or png) with white background color

Tags: c#, svg, transform, jpeg

I'm running the following c# code to convert a SVG file to jpg, however, the files created return with a black background. Is there a good way to create a white background?
Or another solution to create perfect images?

```
var svgDocument = Svg.SvgDocument.Open(file);
var width = svgDocument.Width;
var height = svgDocument.Height;
float factor = outputWidth / width;
int newHeight = (int) Math.Floor(factor * height);
svgDocument.ShapeRendering = SvgShapeRendering.Auto;
Bitmap bmp = svgDocument.Draw(outputWidth, newHeight);
bmp.Save(@"output.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a black background and not just a transparent background, which your image viewer is showing as black?

Comment: The `Draw()` method has different overloads. One accepts a Bitmap, another one accepts a Graphics object. So you can draw on a Bitmap that has a pre-set background color. Another overload accepts an `ISvgRenderer` object that you can configure as needed.